# Amazon S3 permissions granted but users cannot realize their permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am an admin using Amazon S3 and have created an S3 bucket. Under Permissions, and under Access Control List, I have specified AWS users to have "List objects" and "Read bucket permissions." However, those same users are not able to list objects or read from the bucket using AWS CLI.

Is there another step I as an admin need to do to give users permission in S3 using AWS CLI, or is there something they need to do to realize the access I have given them using AWS CLI?

Comment: Their IAM user also need permissions to access S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While granting access on the bucket itself can allow users to access the bucket, the users themselves also need permission to call the Amazon S3 service. If they do not have such permissions, they won't be able to access *any* bucket.

The best way to grant specific users access to an Amazon S3 bucket is to use an IAM Policy. This policy can be placed on an **IAM User**.

If you have a group of users who should receive the same permission, you can create an **IAM Group**, put the users in the group, then add the policy to the IAM Group.

Here is a sample policy from [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This grants permission to list the contents of the `test` bucket and retrieve objects from the bucket.